# Inconsistent key used to encrypt?! How to deal with key expiration?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I have encrypted a file using command:

```
#> gpg --encrypt --recipient RECIPIENT -o c.gpg c
```

This command checks which key it used to encrypt (90FC2A8F):

```
#> gpg --list-packets c.gpg
...
gpg: encrypted with 1024-bit RSA key, ID 90FC2A8F, created 2017-09-28
```

However, when I check keys for the recipient I get this:

```
#> gpg --edit-key RECIPIENT
pub  1024R/17003F4F  created: 2017-09-28  expires: never       usage: SCEA
                     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
sub  1024R/90FC2A8F  created: 2017-09-28  expires: 2025-09-26  usage: SEA
sub  1024R/1A52129E  created: 2017-09-28  expires: 2025-09-26  usage: SEA
```

Can someone explain to me why did it use sub key 90FC2A8F  to encrypt the file instead of pub key 17003F4F?

If I want to collect key expiration for the RECIPIENT, should I search through all ***usage*** that contains 'E', and chose the one that has 'never' or the farthest in time expiration date? Why then the encryption did not chose 'never expire' key?

Note, I can really look at the key in shell running `pgp --list-packets` over the output of 'armored' exported key. It does not contain usage, though!